# Do you know why this C code ends with "segmentation fault"?

Tags: c, shared-memory, semaphore, mmap

Do you know why this C code ends with "segmentation fault"?

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


#define NAMESEM "/mysem"

int main(int argc, char* argv) {
 sem_t* sem;
 int fd = shm_open(NAMESEM, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_TRUNC, 0);

 ftruncate(fd, sizeof(sem_t));

 sem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

 sem_init(sem, 1, 0);

 sem_wait(sem);

 return 0;
}
```

I have followed all the posts found here concerning this, but it seems that sem_init() generates a segmentation fault and I do not know why. Am I making some mistakes with pointers?

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `mmap`?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I have solved this forst problem. But now the second processo when performs shm_open, I get the error "permission denied". process A performs shm_open(NAMESEM, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, O_RDWR); and process B performs shm_open(NAMESEM, O_RDWR , O_RDWR);...is there a permission error?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the flags passed to `shm_open` in this line:

```
int fd = shm_open(NAMESEM, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_TRUNC, 0);
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This means it will work the first time, when `NAMESEM` doesn't exist. Subsequent `shm_opens` will fail because of `O_EXCL`. Which in turn means `ftruncate` and `mmap` will fail. The gist of the issue is that these IPC objects survive after the program dies, until explicitly removed or until the system is restarted.

> `O_EXCL`
>
> If  `O_CREAT` was  also  specified, and a shared memory
>   object with the given name already exists, return an error.

But really the true problem in your code is that **you're not checking the return values for these functions**. A simple `perror` would immediately point out the problems.